# returning different time frames from datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am parsing a file this way :

```
for d in csvReader:
    print datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date"]+"-"+d["Time"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f").date()
```

date() returns : 2000-01-08, which is correct

time() returns : 06:20:00, which is also correct

How would I go about returning informations like **"date+time"** or **"date+hours+minutes"**

**EDIT**

Sorry I should have been more precise, here is what I am trying to achieve :

```
lmb = lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date"]+"-"+d["Time"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f").date()

daily_quotes = {}
for k, g in itertools.groupby(csvReader, key = lmb):
    lowBids = []
    highBids = []
    openBids = []
    closeBids = []
    for i in g:

        lowBids.append(float(i["Low Bid"]))
        highBids.append(float(i["High Bid"]))
        openBids.append(float(i["Open Bid"]))
        closeBids.append(float(i["Close Bid"]))

    dayMin = min(lowBids)
    dayMax = max(highBids)
    open = openBids[0]
    close = closeBids[-1]

    daily_quotes[k.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")] = [dayMin,dayMax,open,close]
```

As you can see, right now I'm grouping values by day, I would like to group them by hour ( for which I would need date + hour ) or minutes ( date + hour + minute )

thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm thinking the `strftime` method of the `datetime` objects you're getting back from `strptime` is what you want, but like Gareth, I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `date` method of the `datetime` object you're getting from `strptime`.  Instead, apply `strftime` directly to the return from `strptime`, which gets you access to all the member fields, including year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, etc...

```
d = {"Date": "01-Jan-2000", "Time": "01:02:03.456"}
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d["Date"]+"-"+d["Time"], "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S.%f")
print dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
```